# Python: how to get all mysql query from cursor

Tags: python, mysql

i have a problem with a print after cursor.execute my query to see what values i have in it

```
query_params = {'id' : id, 'type': type }
query = ("SELECT * from table WHERE id=%(id)s and type IN (%(type)s) ;")    
cursor.execute(query_inc, query_inc_params)
print(cursor)
```

but i got in terminal row with a sql query like

```
MySQLCursorDict: SELECT * from v_comments WHERE inc_id=33..
```

how to get all row with query in cursor?

Comment: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchall

Comment: how to use this?

Comment: print(cursor._executed) worked for me